# Add items to dhtmlDataView from XML file

Tags: dhtmlx

In case of grid it is possible to add new rows from XML file using updateFromXML() method without reloading the whole batch of data. Is it possible to add new items to dhtmlxDataView in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just call the load command second time.

```
dataview.load("extra_data.php");
```

Load command will add new items and update the existing ones ( just be sure that each item has unique id )